# Identityserver4 Access levels Practices

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, identityserver4

We're looking for 3 types of different access levels but don't know how to implement them using current **identityserver4** features. 
Have these scenarios:

- We have an **upper management system** which some clients have access to specific pages or not, like admin or client(seems like **Roles**)
- We have **column type access level**, for example, some users in the manager role can see a specific column/field or not, or in **same roles** shouldn't see some column/row data in reports.
- We have **a record level, access level**, for example, some manager shouldn't see other branch client list. (like policies)

The whole process should be dynamic without any hardcode. and for doing these structures we should do some code on the back-end(middleware, etc) and some on frontend side(with a razor or etc).

any Idea how to implement these using identityserver4 authorization types?

Comment: I think you are confusing authorization and authentication.   Identity server authenticates your user.   What authorization they have it not its job to determine.

Answer (score 4):

The main feature of IdentityServer is to handle the authentication of the user and global authorization: which client has access to what resource.

Everything else could be considered out-of-scope of IdentityServer. Please read [this article](https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/) for some background information.

As an answer they've created the [PolicyServer](https://policyserver.io/).

In the OSS version authorization has become a seperate (local) mechanism, while the paid version outsources authorization to a seperate server.

Extended with [resource-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased) you can implement authorization that covers all access levels.